# Radio Buttons are causing flicker effect on buttons in dialog actions Material UI version 4

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, button, material-ui, radio-button

I am Using Material UI version 4, I have a dialog box which is custom and being used all over the project.

[codeSandBox LInk](https://n9z7c.csb.app/)

Inside dialog there is a form with textFeilds, radio buttons and buttons in dialog actions. Buttons are flickering when radio buttons are present and diableTouchRipple={false}. flickering effect is on middle and right most button. if I have only single button  or disableTouchRipple={true} on middle button then buttons are not flickeing. Flickering is only present in Google Chrome, it's not present in firefox, brave, or edge [image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Here is the horrible hack I finally found:

In the dialog add a div with some value like 'test' and with the properties zIndex: 1, position: "absolute". You can also add an opacity: 0 to hide it though to get it to work in your sandbox I had to set the opacity to 0.0001.

Here is the forked sandbox with the change: https://codesandbox.io/s/dialog-actions-button-flicker-effect-in-chrome-forked-x1ntb